# Блок для категории, uCoz

Tags: cms, интернет-магазин, ucoz

Есть сайт в ucoz. Установлен модуль интернет магазина, есть категории, структурно абсолютно идентичные друг другу, понятно что отличаются по названиям и содержащимся в них товарах. Так вот - в одну, конкретную категорию, допустим Мебель, нужно встроить дополнительный блок после всех товаров, обычный калькулятор-конструктор. Так вот как сделать это в ucoz? Чтобы в других категориях этого калькулятора не было? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Если калькулятор уже есть и\или это виджет от самого юкоза, то достаточно на нужной странице его вставить и обернуть его условным оператором:

```
<?if($CAT_ID$==**Сюда ид категории "Мебель"**)?>
  **Тут код калькулятора**
<?endif?>
```